# engraved imprint detection on pills using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
# import bm3d
img = cv2.imread('1_2_2.png')
# img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(13,13),0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# gray = cv2.medianBlur(, 5)
# cv2.imshow("img", gray)
# gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | 
cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
[1]
v = np.median(gray)
sigma = 0.33
#---- apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median-- 
--
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
gray = cv2.Canny(img,lower,upper)
# ret,gray = cv2.threshold(gray,110,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kernel = np.ones((4,4),np.uint8)
gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
gray = cv2.dilate(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
# gray = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)\
# gray = cv2.erode(gray,kernel,iterations = 1)
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
cv2.imshow("threshold", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray)
print(text)
```

[image]

I am trying some image processing as mentioned in the code but not able to get the one which pytesseract can detect.
please help is there any work done to detect the engravings

[seen that stack overflow link but did't get the proper idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630114/how-to-ocr-engraved-text)

Comment: I would recommend using binarization rather then edge detection.

Comment: thanks for responding @SilverMonkey let me try it and will share the result

Comment: @SilverMonkey binarization is not giving results giving black and white image not able to detect imprit

Comment: the image is of low resolution as well as blurred . is this a client provided image or you have downloaded it from google for POC/POV purpose?

Comment: @Saurav I haven't downloaded I took the picture and separated them into crops, this is the best quality I can get (have only one camera) can you give me some reference to get the imprint

Comment: @Saurav look at the second white image I have uploaded can it be detected??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Note: This is just a starter's code. You can play around with it, and also it involves a lot of `threshold` values, which you need to experiment with. Of course this is not the best code, but you can use it as a starting point.

I will briefly outline the steps below, and provide the `python` code after that along with the `output` that it generates at each step.

- Load image in *Grayscale*
- Perform *Adaptive Threshold* with a large `kernel size`. It is
  important to perform *Adaptive Threshold*, rather than some *Global
  Threshold*, as it takes neighboring intensity into account, which
  plays an important role in the example image provided by you.
- Perform *Median Blur* to get rid of *salt and pepper noise*.
- Find the *Connected Components* with considerable area, and remove
  *small island noise* from the final image.
- Plot the final *contours* into the output image.

The `python` code to achieve this is provided below:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('test.png')
output = np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],3), np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C  , cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 1)

median = cv2.medianBlur(threshold, 11)
median = cv2.bitwise_not(median)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(median,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

saved_cont = []
thresh = 100

for contour in contours:
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > thresh:
        print(cv2.contourArea(contour))
        saved_cont.append(contour)

cv2.drawContours(output, saved_cont,-1,(255,255,255),1)

cv2.imshow('original', gray)
cv2.imshow('threshold', threshold)
cv2.imshow('median', median)
cv2.imshow('contour', output)

cv2.imwrite("threshold.png", threshold)
cv2.imwrite("median.png", median)
cv2.imwrite("output.png", output)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original Image:

[image]

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Median Blurred Image:

[image]

Final Output:

[image]

Some other *morphological operations* that you may want to experiment with are **Dilation**, **Erosion**, **Opening** and **Closing** operations. The documentation can be found over [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

Answer (score 2):

it is a typical industrial application.

What you need for your set up, it is a right illumination:
http://www.vision-doctor.com/en/illumination-techniques/dark-field-illumination.html
Here is the explanation to it. With a little creativity you can build a prototype at home, for example, with a LED stripe.

With gray morphology you can strengthen dark regions for easier segmentation of engraved letters.

The best way to learn, how to do it, if you download the test version of HALCON and execute the examples to pharmaceutical industry and to OCR in HALCON IDE HDevelop. In the examples you can learn how to use matching of logos, to get the orientation of the pill. Then you can transform the image to horizontal orientation to do segmentation and perform OCR. If you don't have any logo, use the imprint as model for shape-based matching and then transform the image, so the letters are horizontally oriented and then segment letters and perform OCR.
There is no general recipe, every application is unique. But you can learn a lot from examples to build your own application.

Best regards,
Dorothea